# In symfony, how can i get Global methods and variables in any Controller?

Tags: php, symfony

The scene is, the client (All request like Ajax in my site) will request a json string like that `{"token":"mytoken"}`.PHP receive it by `$request->getContent()` and `json_decode` it. I store it in a variable named `$data` so i can get it in any Controller.

I also create a method to get value by key, code like that

```
public function input($key, $default = '', $func = '')
{
    $ret = '';
    if (isset($this->data[$key])) {
        $ret = $this->data[$key];
    } else {
        return $default;
    }
    if (is_string($func)) {
        if (in_array($func, ['int', 'string', 'array'])) {
            settype($ret, $func);
            return $ret;
        }
        if ($func)
            $ret = call_user_func($func, $ret);
    } elseif (is_array($func)) {
        if ($func)
            $ret = call_user_func_array($func, [$ret]);
    }
    if (!$ret)
        return $default;
    return $ret;
}
```

Although i can reg it to server, but i use it like that `$this->get('input')->input($mykey);`, this will appear in any controller. Is this a proposed solution?
The question just my title, HOW? Save me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding a request event listener that parses the JSON and sets the resulting data in the request object. Example implementation:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class ParseJsonRequestListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        // only parse the content body if the content type is JSON
        if (preg_match('/\bjson\b/', $request->getContentType())) {
            $parameters = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

            if ($parameters) {
                $request->request->replace($parameters);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Register the listener, for example in app/config/services.yml:

```
parse_json_request_listener:
    class: ParseJsonRequestListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request }
```

Now in any controller that receives a JSON request, you can get the parsed JSON data from the request, for example:

```
<?php

$token = $request->request->get('token');
```

Comment: Thank you so much !  it's perfect for my confusion,  thku

Answer (score 0):

If a method is in controller, then you can add $request object to params:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
//...
public function input(Request $request, $key, $default = '', $func = '')
//...
```

Request object has all global vars. More info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object